# Why does Pylint think that comparing to zero is bad?

Tags: python, pylint

The optional `comparetozero` extension to pylint checks for any comparison to `0` and flags it. It is unclear to me why this is bad to do.

[According to the docstring](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/pylint/extensions/comparetozero.py#L23) of the `comparetozero` module,

> Most of the times you should use the fact that integers with a value of 0 are false.
>
> An exception to this rule is when 0 is allowed in the program and has a different meaning than None!

What exactly does this mean?

My understanding of the above is that it means that you should not do something like

```py
def return_false():
    return False

if return_false() == 0:
    pass
```

because that is abusing the falsy nature of `0`, but that it is okay to do

```py
if foo % 4 == 0:
    pass
```

because you are comparing two integers to see if they are both literally zero.

If my understanding is correct, is it better to make specific `# pylint: disable` statements for the instances where you are literally checking if a value is zero, or what?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, that does not answer: why is the the removal of the `== 0` considered superior.

Comment: I'm pretty much convinced by their own documentation that this is not a great check.  The example here is even worse: https://vald-phoenix.github.io/pylint-errors/plerr/errors/compare-to-zero/C2001.html.  They claim that an explicit cast to `bool` is better than `== 0` - ridiculous.  This check literally states **checking if an `int` is `0` is not good practice.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pythonic way of comparison is to use implicit boolean checks or truthy values. For e.g.

```
some_val = 0
if some_val == 0: # non-pythonic way to check

vs 

if not some_val: # 0 is false for python and hence a boolean way is easier to read
```

Its better coding practice to say "If this is not true" and the truthy value of a variable is based on various forms such as an empty list, or empty string

So all in all, the following reads better:

```
some_str = ''
if not some_str: # better than if some_str == ''

some_number = 0
if not some_number: # better than if some_number == 0

some_list = []
if not some_list: # better than if len(some_list) == 0
```

Comment: This seems logical. Is there a PEP for this?